# Error in aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1-node16 in github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions

I'm facing this error that I don't understand because I'm using the same pipeline in another repo and it never showed me this error:

```
Run aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1-node16
  with:
    aws-region: us-east-1
    audience: sts.amazonaws.com
Error: Credentials could not be loaded, please check your action inputs: Could not load credentials from any providers
```

here is my code:

```
steps:
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1-node16
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
```

they recommended to use this:

```
build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
       id-token: write
       contents: read
```

I tried it but didn't work also.

Comment: Does this repo also contain those secrets?

Comment: @azeem yes indeed

Comment: Right. Did you try using another STS token?

Comment: From that error and also from the [source code](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/blob/c719b7b5e1d04c14edc4ed28f4ac39d5385d9d28/index.js#L214-L231), this looks like an invalid credentials' issue.